# How to speed up image loading from a server - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am still a beginner in Android and java. I am trying to load an image from a server by using AsyncTask. The size of the image is around 50kb. Yet it takes several seconds to show up. The following code is used to download the image from the server.

```
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {

    try {

        URL url = new URL(src);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        connection.setDoInput(true);

        connection.connect();

        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

        return myBitmap;

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;

    }
```

Can someone please tell me how to speed up this process. What are the factors this process depends on apart from the network speed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest you to search image size reduce algorithms. Then, you can choose some methologies to load picture. For example, in first step, you can load low sized images. After that , you can load normal size images in background and update each reduced sized images to normal sized images.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great resource on loading Bitmaps efficiently.

[Android Developer site - Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

It also includes a code sample.